# 4 table join so that only 1 response is given for each company instead of a result for each campaign

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Thanks for your help!

I'd like to output all companyName entries that have uploads across any of their serverFiles as:

**companies.companyName  -   count(files.fileID)  -  sum(serverFiles.uniqueUploads)**

```
Initech Ltd.   -  11 -  24931
Epiphyte  Inc.  -  23  - 938821
```

Here are the relavent parts of my table structure:

**Table: companies**

```
companyID (INT)  -  companyName (TEXT)
```

**Table: campaigns**

```
campaignID(INT)  -  companyID (INT)
```

**Table: files**

```
fileID (INT)  -  campaignID (INT)
```

**Table: serverFiles**
    serverFileID (INT)  -  fileID (INT)  -  uniqueUploads(INT)

Each company can have multiple campaigns.

Each campaign can have multiple files.

Each file can have multiple serverFiles

The query I tried to use is as follows:

```
SELECT companies.companyName, sum(serverFiles.uniqueUploads), count(files.fileID)
FROM companies
INNER JOIN campaigns on companies.companyID = campaigns.companyID
INNER JOIN files on files.campaign = campaigns.campaignID
LEFT OUTER JOIN serverFiles on serverfiles.fileID = files.fileID
GROUP BY serverFiles.uniqueUploads, files.fileID
ORDER BY sum(serverFiles.uniqueUploads) DESC;
```

However, this returns multiple entries for each company (as it creates multiple outputs for each company - one for each campaign under the company).

eg:

**companies.companyName  -   count(files.fileID)  -  sum(serverFiles.uniqueUploads)**

```
Initech Ltd.   -  2 -  234234     (for initech campaign1)
Initech Ltd.   -  4 -  223323    (for initech campaign2)
Epiphyte  Inc.  -  13  - 6434   (for epiphyte campaign1)
Initech Ltd.   -  1 -  554     (for initech campaign3)
Epiphyte  Inc.  -  13  - 7544   (for epiphyte campaign2)
Epiphyte  Inc.  -  11  - 74545   (for epiphyte campaign3)
Epiphyte  Inc.  -  23  - 456544   (for epiphyte campaign4)
```

How do I change the query to only give me one response back for each company, summing up all of the campaigns under that company.

Thanks so much for any assistance.

Comment: +1 for using initech, but this looks like a simple group by solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine, I think, except for the GROUP BY clause.  Should be

```
GROUP BY companies.companyName
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the company name to the group and perform a MIN/MAX to grab one in the select list.

```
SELECT MAX(companies.companyName), sum(serverFiles.uniqueUploads), count(files.fileID)
FROM companies
INNER JOIN campaigns on companies.companyID = campaigns.companyID
INNER JOIN files on files.campaign = campaigns.campaignID
LEFT OUTER JOIN serverFiles on serverfiles.fileID = files.fileID
GROUP BY companies.companyName, serverFiles.uniqueUploads, files.fileID
ORDER BY sum(serverFiles.uniqueUploads) DESC;
```